# Make a column be unaffected by any row in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, iwork-numbers

Basically I want to keep a particular column unaffected by any row deletion (by unaffected, I mean no contents of that column are shifted). Is this even possible?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it might be better if you explained your goal and *why* you need to do this. Fundamentally, this isn't something a spreadsheet program would *want* to do as it would destroy the structure of the data (think of it like a relational database).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am doing it as a grader of a course, where I keep a spreadsheet of grades. The column that I want unaffected are statistics on the calculated grades (i.e. how many got A+, A, etc.) for each part of the course (exams, assignments, etc.) and I display them next to that column. I want them unaffected because if a student drops, I delete that row, and it messes up the statistics.